# Is there a minimizing geodesic between the less moving point and its image by an isometry?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, isometry

First of all sorry for the clunchy title, I had no idea how to phrase it better.

Take $M$ a Riemann connected compact manifold with induced distance $d$, let $\phi:M\to M$ be an isometry. We define $p_0$ as the point minimizing $M\to\mathbb{R}:p\mapsto d(p,\phi(p))$

Is it true that there exists a minimizing geodesic that goes from $p_0$ to $\phi(p_0)$?

It's part of an exercice I'm trying to do, so even some suggestions from where I can work on will be very appreciated.

I have the feeling that, as we take $p_0$ in this way, it's possible to show that $\phi(p_0)$ is in the image of the exponential map of $p_0$, and therefore there is a minimmizing geodesic. But I don't know how to prove it (if it's true).

Comment: For a complete Riemannina manifold, any two points can be joined by a geodesic that realizes the distance between them. Moreover, any compact Riemannian manifold is complete. So yes.

Comment: Oh, yea, right... Well, sorry everyone. It was just a case of "ignore unuseful information"